# Confused about the relation between linear transformations, matrices and basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I was watching 3blue1brown's video series on linear algebra. My understanding till now is :-

1. A linear transformation takes in a vector and outputs another vector.
2. The above statement is equivalent to multiplying a unique matrix to the given vector.
3. 3b1b shows the linear transformation using a new coordinate system, and shows that $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ change.
4. When he discusses change of basis, he states that it helps us move between different coordinate systems.
5. 3b1b also states that a matrix implicitly assumes coordinate systems, as it represents the landing spots of basis vectors after linear transformation.
6. He shows how to transform a rotation matrix in a conventional Cartesian coordinate system, to Jennifer's coordinate system (one where basis vectors are not perpendicular to one another).

Points 4,5 and 6 have really confused me and now I doubt even points 1,2 and 3.

When we write a matrix what basis vectors does it assume? I have never seen any text stating that this assumes a Cartesian coordinate system. I always assumed that it is somehow independent of coordinate systems.

My second question: I thought that a linear transformation doing a 90° counter-clockwise rotation is represented by a unique matrix \begin{equation*}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1  \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
but, as was shown in the video for Jennifer's choice of basis vectors the same 90° counter-clockwise rotation linear transformation is in fact \begin{equation*}
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & -2/3  \\
5/3 & -1/3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
It seems like a linear transformation has a one-one mapping to a unique matrix **only** for a given set of basis vectors. Thus, the same matrix can refer to different linear transformations if we choose a different basis vector. In case, I am correct, could you provide a mathematically rigorous way of writing this down (using math symbols). I feel that I understand concepts better if I can write it in a mathematical form, instead of relying solely on intuition.

Comment: For your first question: If a text does not specify the basis in which it is working, then you can always think that you are working with the canonical basis, namely $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$. Remember that, if you are working in a vector space $V$ of dimension $2$ and basis $\{ v_1 , v_2 \}$, then it is exactly as working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with canonical basis.

Comment: I changed the title from "Confused between matrix multiplication and the change of basis matrix" to the current title.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @DavideMotta. Much appreciated!

Comment: Also, @DavideMotta; could you help me with my 2nd question as well? Thanks!

Comment: As a professor told me: "The canonical basis is the 
 most beautiful basis in the realm". This means, the simplest basis that comes in your mind, This is exactly done with $e_1 = (1,0,0 \dots , 0), e_2 = (0,1,0, \dots, 0), \dots, e_n =(0,0,0 \dots , 1)$  in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $e_i$ is a vector with coordinates equal zero except for that one in position $i$ where it takes the value $1$

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Roy.

Comment: "It seems like a linear transformation has a one-one mapping to a unique matrix only for a given set of basis vectors. Thus, the same matrix can refer to different linear transformations if we choose a different basis vector." This is correct.  It sounds like your understanding is fine.  It's just that, as others have mentioned, when interpreting a matrix as a linear transformation we assume the basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the standard basis $(1,0, \ldots, 0), (0, 1, 0, \ldots), \ldots$ unless another basis is indicated.

Comment: For your second question: I think it's better to reverse the point of view. The same given linear transformation can refer to different matrices if you choose a different basis vector. You can do imagine it: pick a pencil, you say "oh this is a pencil". Now invert your head. Here you say "oh! This is the same pencil but I'm watching it from another point of view". This means: the same transformation (pencil) has a lot of representations, i.e. matrices, one for each change of basis (invert your head).

Comment: If you want to take a look for more formal statements about changes of basis, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: There’s an important thing that your list is missing. Vectors aren’t necessarily ordered tuples of scalars. They can be polynomials, continuous function, or many other kinds of objects. In order to represent application of a linear transformation to a vector as a matrix multiplication, you also have to convert that vector into an ordered tuple of scalars. That in itself involves choosing an ordered basis for the vector space—the elements of that tuple are the vector’s coordinates relative to the basis. This is often glossed over when the vector space itself consists of ordered tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector is an element of a vector space. An element of a vector space can be an $n$-tuple of numbers, a polynomial, a matrix, a function etc.

A linear transformation transforms a vector ($n$-tuple, polynomial, matrix, function, etc.) into another vector ($n$-tuple, polynomial, matrix, function, etc.). A matrix cannot transform a vector into another vector, because you can multiply a matrix by an $n$-tuple, but you can't multiply a matrix by a polynomial, a matrix (well, not always, see below), a function, etc.

A matrix associated to a linear transformation can only multiply $n$-tuples of coordinates respect to a basis, and the results are $n$-tuples of coordinates respect to a basis.

Imagine that your vector space is the set of all symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices, and that your linear transformation is:$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix} c & a \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}$$

The simplest basis is: $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$.

Respect to this basis the coordinates of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$ are $(a,b,c)$, the coordinates of $\begin{bmatrix} c & a \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}$ are $(c,a,b)$.

The matrix associated to $T$ respect to that basis is: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

You can't multiply $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ by $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$, but:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c \\ a \\ b \end{bmatrix}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\text{Coord}\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}\right)=\text{Coord}\left(\begin{bmatrix} c & a \\ a & b \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
This is why:

- you always need a basis to associate a matrix to a linear
  transformation (when the basis is omitted you assume the canonical basis),
- the matrix associated to a linear transformation is unique respect to
  a fixed basis,
- you can also have different bases for the domain and the range of a
  linear transformation, so the matrix associated to a linear transformation is unique respect to the basis of its domain and the basis of its range,
- since there are infinite bases, there also are infinite matrices
  associated to a linear transformation.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio! I really appreciate the detail you went into!

Comment: @ManishBhat You are welcome, happy to be useful.